# Dropdown list giving Class Name not values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist from a database table and am using this code in my controller

```
model.EngineerNameList = new List<Engineers>();
foreach (string Engineer in allData.Select(x => x.EngineerName).Distinct().ToList())
{
    model.EngineerNameList.Add(new Engineers() { EngineerName = Engineer });
}
```

This is returning the correct number of items in my drop down list but i am getting the name of the class as defined in my class here

```
public partial class Engineers
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string EngineerName { get; set; }
}
```

i am displaying in my view using the following

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Engineer">Select Engineer:</label>
    <select id="Name" name="Name" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        @if (Model.EngineerNameList != null)
        {
            foreach (var Title in Model.EngineerNameList)
            {
            <option value="@Title" >@Title </option>
            }
        }
        </select>
</div>
```

My problem is I cannot get the value contained in the class into the dropdown list. This is what i get on my page:

[image]

Comment: Change it to <option value="@Title.EngineerName " >@Title.EngineerName  </option>

Comment: Pro tip: calling `.ToString()` on an object of a class you created will give you a string with the class name (and namespace) unless you've specifically overriden the `ToString()` method for your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EngineerNameList` is a collection of `Engineers` model, so when you iterating over it you will get an object of `Engineers`. That's why you are seeing to `ToString()` representation of your Model in the dropdown list.

So to show appropriate engineer name, update the code as

```
<option value="@Title.EngineerName">@Title.EngineerName</option>
```

Comment: Note that `Title` isn't a great name for the variable; it displays the error of OP's assumption that he was working with a list of names (titles) as opposed to a list of engineers.

Comment: Thanks thats worked perfectly i knew it had to be something simple i had missed

Comment: @Flater - Completely agree with you.  Choosing good names is an Art! If one is not careful, then it's very easy for variable names to spiral out of control. Before one know it the benefit is lost because variable names are hard to recall and end up causing more frustration than benefit :)

Comment: Have now changed variable name was taken from a general example on google when i started thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this type in MVC with razor helpers

```
 <select id="Name" name="Name" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    @if (Model.EngineerNameList != null)
    {
        foreach (var Title in Model.EngineerNameList)
        {
       <option value="@Title.EngineerName">@Title.EngineerName</option>
        }
    }
    </select>
```

**Can be replace with**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor("EngineerName", Model.EngineerNameList.Select(Title => new SelectListItem { Text = Title.EngineerName, Value = Title.EngineerName.ToString() }))
```

It will also reflect same html code after rendering...